# Configuring NAT with ufw instead iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, ufw

I want to apply this iptables rule:

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 87.13.180.182 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.13
```

(87blabla is my public ip and 192blabla is my private ip).

People suggested me to use ufw instead iptables since it's easier to use.

So I:

1) Set **DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"** on /etc/default/ufw 
2) Set **net.ipv4.ip_forward=1** on  /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf 
3) Created the **NAT table** and added my rule on /etc/ufw/before.rules

//Nat table 
*nat 
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

//Nat rule 
PREROUTING -d 87.13.180.182 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.13

But it doesen't work when i run ufw disable && ufw enable (error on that line).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 87.13.180.182 -j DNAT –to-destination 192.168.0.13
```